# Splitting a `.bed` file based on chromosomes into `chromosomeName.bed` with perl

Tags: perl, file, split

I am trying to use `perl` to split a `.bed` file into multiple ones based on chromosome. For example, my input file is `example.bed`:

```
chr1    12190   12227
chr1    12595   12721
chr2    876522  876688
chr2    887378  887521
...
```

And my ideal output is two `.bed` files:

**chr1.bed**

```
chr1    12190   12227
chr1    12595   12721
```

**chr2.bed**

```
chr2    876522  876688
chr2    887378  887521
```

I know using `awk` to do this is easier, but I am hoping to figure out how to do this using a `perl` script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can maintain a hash of filehandles:

```
$ cat example.bed 
chr1 12190 12227
chr1 12595 12721
chr2 876522 876688
chr2 887378 887521

$ perl -ane '
    open $out{$F[0]}, ">", $F[0].".bed" unless $out{$F[0]}; 
    print { $out{$F[0]} } $_;
' example.bed

$ cat chr1.bed
chr1 12190 12227
chr1 12595 12721

$ cat chr2.bed
chr2 876522 876688
chr2 887378 887521
```

If you have hundreds of different chromasomes, you may run out of open filehandles. In that case, you'll have to open for append, print and close for each line.

Comment: And, yeah, the awk is equivalent but simpler: `awk '{f = $1 ".bed"; print > f}' example.bed`

Answer (score 1):

A tad verbose, maybe, but will allow flexibility if you need to manipulate(sort, search, etc) the content. As a rule, if the data file fits into memory, I much prefer to stuff the entire file into memory and go from there.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# initialize the hash to contain the content    
my %bed;
# read the entire file into memory
# stuffing same into a hash
while(<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    my @line = split;
    my $car = $line[0];
    my $cdr = join(' ', @line[1,-1]);
    push(@{$bed{$car}}, $cdr);
}

foreach my $k (keys %bed)
{
    # create filename
    my $fn = $k . '.txt';
    # open file for writing
    open OUT, '>', $fn or die "Cannot open $fn, $!";
    # print each element of the hash key
    foreach my $e (@{$bed{$k}}) { print OUT "$e\n"; }
    # close file`
    close OUT;
}
exit(0);    

__DATA__
chr1    12190   12227
chr1    12595   12721
chr2    876522  876688
chr2    887378  887521
```